# Webix Filemanager add Custom stacked Font Awesome Icon

Tags: icons, font-awesome, nsfilemanager, webix

How can I add custom icons in webix FileManager:

```
How to add customized icons for webix FileManager.

trying below code, but not working:

 templateIcon: function (obj, common) {                    
                    return "<span class='webix_icon webix_fmanager_icon fa-stack fa-lg'><i class='webix_icon webix_fmanager_icon fa fa-folder fa-stack-2x'></i><i class='webix_icon webix_fmanager_icon fa fa-lock fa-stack-1x'></i></span>";
                },
```

I need to add stacked icons under some conditions, like below:
    
        
        
      `enter code here

Comment: I need to add stacked icons under some conditions, like below:
    'code' '<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
        <i class="fa fa-folder fa-stack-2x"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-lock fa-stack-1x"></i>
      </span>'

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your templateIcon works. Did you define it in FileManager configuration:

```
webix.ui({
   view:"filemanager",
   id:"files",
   templateIcon: function (obj, common) {
       return ...
   }
});
```

And this function can define different icons depending on an item type. The first parameter of templateicon function is data item. So, you can check 'type' property of an item return the corresponding result.